# Эффективно найти средний элемент в set'е

Tags: c++

`std::set` обычно представлен бинарным деревом поиска. У него есть методы `begin` и `end`, которые позволяют получить минимум и максимум, а также `lower_bound` и `upper_bound` для бинарного поиска. А что если мне надо получить итератор, указывающий на элемент в середине сета (или один из них, если в нём чётное число элементов)?

Есть ли эффективный способ сделать это (за `O(log(size))` вместо `O(size)`)?

```
{1} => 1
{1,2} => 1 или 2
{1,2,3} => 2
{1,2,3,4} => 2 или 3 (но в ту же сторону от середины, что и с {1,2})
{1,312,10000,14000,152333} => 10000
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/47376322/4928642)

Comment: кстати, удалять элементы надо или нет?

Comment: @pavel, да, надо и вставлять, и удалять. Иначе можно было бы просто отсортировать вектор.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47376322/4928642

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Или, если все-таки использовать `set`, то можно поддерживать итератор, указывающий на медианный элемент и число элементов `k` до этого итератора.

- Изначально `set` пустой, итератор равен `set.end()`, `k` равно нулю
- При добавлении элемента в `set`:

  - новый элемент больше медианного => при необходимости (если `k * 2 + 3 <= set.size()`) сдвигааем итератор на один вперед и увеличиваем `k` на единицу.
  - новый элемент меньше медианного => при необходимости сдвигааем итератор на один назад и уменьшаем `k` на единицу.
- При удалении элемента из `set` действуем аналогично, при необходимости двигаем итератор на единицу вперед/назад
- Таким образом, в любой момент времени у нас есть итератор на медианный элемент, дополнительные расходы для поддержания этого итератора составляют `O(log n)` на каждую операцию вставки/удаления

И еще вот [полезный вопрос на английском Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10657503) примерно про это же (там без удаления, но идея такая же)

Answer (score 2):

Если писать свое декартово дерево не хочется, то можно использовать встроенную в gcc структуру данных [`rope`](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/10355?locale=ru)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что нет. Ну смотрите, для поиска минимума в BST нужно всегда идти в левую ветку, максимума - в правую. И вот хотите Вы найти средний. И с самого начала неизвестно, что делать. Условно, у вас в корне дерева стоит "10", больше Вы ничего не знаете о содержимом. Куда пойдете?

Comment: ответ не верен... есть множество структур которым это не мешает.

Comment: @pavel Возможно, я не совсем понял вопрос и имел ввиду решение этой задачи именно на BST

Comment: формально декартово дерево тоже BST. просто в вершину число элементов в поддереве записать.

Comment: Если вершина знает число элементов в поддереве, то куда идти известно.